# Reference for chain rule for continuously Frechet differentiable maps

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $f\colon L^p(\Omega;X) \to L^q(\Omega;Y)$ and $g\colon L^q(\Omega;Y) \to L^r(\Omega;Z)$ where $X,Y,Z$ are separable Hilbert spaces and $\Omega$ is a smooth and bounded open set (eg. $\Omega = [0,T]$).

If these maps are continuously Frechet differentiable, under what conditions on the exponents do we obtain that $g \circ f \colon L^p(\Omega;X) \to L^r(\Omega;Z)$ is also continuously Frechet differentiable?

Does anyone know of a reference?

Comment: This is just the chain rule for Frechet differentiable maps. No (additional) conditions on $p,q,r$ required.

Comment: The chain rule is proved in almost any multivariable calculus text. For example, see Loomis and Sternberg's *Advanced Calculus*, or Henri Cartan's *Differential Calculus*, or Dieudonne's *Treatise on Analysis Volume I* for the Banach space setting. Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* or Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* also have proofs (they're stated in the context of maps $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ but with very minor modifications the proofs hold for arbitrary Banach spaces).

Comment: @peek-a-boo all of those references hold for normed spaces (no need of completeness in general, except when dealing with open maps or integral; for chain rule, no need of completeness for sure).

Comment: @WilliamM. sure; much of the basics rules of calculus can be developed for normed spaces (I just didn't mention it due to lack of space in a comment section:)